Hund's rules in Helium level scheme
If I am not wrong, Hund's rules state that:
I) The highest $2S+1$ has the lowest energy.
II) For a given $S$, the lowest $L$ has the highest energy.
However, I have found in various textbooks the level scheme for Helium, where the order is $D > P > S$. (See the image below for the $n = 3, S = 0$ states.) How is this possible?


You cannot do it on Hydrogen. There is only one electron in Hydrogen atom and the stuff that Hund's rules are used to discern between, are degenerate in that case.

Hund's rules can only predict the energetic ordering of states arising from the same configuration. For example, $E(2 \, {^3S})<E(2 \, {^1S})$ can be guessed from the first rule, because the dominant configuration giving rise to both states is $(1s)(2s)$; the same holds for states $3 \, {^3P}$, $3 \, {^1P}$ originating from $(1s)(3p)$ and so on. Similarly for doubly excited states (these are above the ionization threshold, so not visible in your picture), the $(2p)^2$ configuration generates three states, $^1S$, $^3P_g$ and $^1D$, the energy order $E(^3P_g)<E(^1D)<E(^1S)$ displaying both the first and second rule: the triplet state has the lowest energy, and between the two singlets, the lower energy state is the one with the higher orbital angular momentum.
Hund's rules are not predictive for other kinds of states. The three states $3 \, {^1S}$, $3 \, {^1P}$ and $3 \, {^1D}$ arise from three different configurations ($(1s)(3s)$, $(1s)(3p)$, $(1s)(3d)$, respectively), so these rules cannot say anything useful about them. The same goes for the triplets. You can only compare them pairwise: $E(3 \, {^3S})<E(3 \, {^1S})$, $E(3 \, {^3P})<E(3 \, {^1P})$ and $E(3 \, {^3D})<E(3 \, {^1D})$. Curiously, the $3 \, {^1P}$ state seems to be a little bit below $3 \, {^3P}$ in the picture, but this cannot be correct (see e.g. NIST).
For some further details on Hund's rules, take a look at my other answer.

Thank you very much, that was very helpfull!
